# NFSv4 ACLs on ZFS and other permissions

Tags: permissions, freebsd, zfs, acl, nfsv4

All,

I've been experimenting with using NFSv4 ACLs on ZFS datasets to set default permissions in a handful of directories that are accessed using a few different means (eg. SFTP, NFS, etc.) I've been able to implement most of the changes I'd like with the exception of masking other permissions for new files. For example, I'd like for new files in a directory to default to 0660 - I can't seem to find the right combination or ordering to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated!